# Where is the ID chip in this card?

Tags: smartcard, identity

I recently attended a Salesforce World Tour. As part of being identifiable and being marketable you get this ID card that the exhibitors scan, so that they can get your name, company, email and whatnot. I was curious as to what chip or antenna is in this card. So I cut it in several strips in the hope to find something, but all I can see is solid plastic.

Where is the 'identifier'? Is the actual chip or antenna so thin that I can't make it out with my naked eye? Or is there another hardware piece that I haven't found yet?

If it helps, here are two images. First one shows the card cut in stripes in the hope to locate something that identified me at the booths.
[image: The card cut in stripes]

The second image shows the cross cut section of one of the middle pieces. I've left it in the original's resolution, but it doesn't seem to reveal anything.
[image: Cross cut section of one of the middle pieces of the card]

Comment: It would be an RFID chip.

Comment: Thanks, but where could it be? I wasn't able to see anything in the strips. They basically all look like the one in the second photo.

Comment: A typical passive RFID chip can be as small as 1mmx1mm. You'll need to cut up your card much smaller than what you show in the image to have a chance of finding them.

Comment: It's located at one of the corners https://learn.adafruit.com/rfid-iphone/dissolve-the-card

Comment: @AlexIxeras try using acetone to dissolve it. The link shard by the guy above does suggest a good method of "melting" the card and revealing the chip.

Comment: Is the plastic translucent? Get a really really bright torch and shine it through the card, and you'll probably see the antenna and the chip.

Comment: @Shiji.Jiang Thanks for the advice. I'll give that a try. It could actually mean I cut the antenna too, but I'll report back, when I've completed it.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere the card is very opaque. I can't see through it, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: @AlexIxeras Did you ever find the chip?